# Google Drive migration Python script

Tags: python, linux

I am looking to see if someone is willing to take the challenge in optimizing this noob python script.

The purpose of the script is to:

1. Check if Google Drive File Stream is installed
2. Check if Google Drive is installed
3. Check if user's Google Drive folder has been renamed

Then the actions begin:

1. Install Google Drive File Stream
2. Quit Google Drive if running
3. Uninstall Google Drive
4. Rename user'sGoogle Drive folder

Logging is needed, of course, and some double checks for various commands you'll see in the script.

```
import commands
import subprocess
import os, logging, sys, signal, time, shutil
from SystemConfiguration import SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser

##################################################################################
# Variables
##################################################################################
userName = (SCDynamicStoreCopyConsoleUser(None, None, None) or [None])[0]
userName = [userName,""][userName in [u"loginwindow", None, u""]]
googleDriveDir = ""
gdfsInstaller = "/Library/Scripts/Company/GoogleDriveFileStream.dmg"
# Logging File
#logFile = "/Library/Logs/Company/googleDrive_Migration.log"
logFile = "/Users/" + userName + "/Library/Logs/Company/googleDrive_Migration.log"
basedir = os.path.dirname(logFile)
if not os.path.exists(basedir):
    os.makedirs(basedir)
if not os.path.exists(logFile):
    with open(logFile, 'a'):
        os.utime(logFile, None)

logging.basicConfig(filename=logFile, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
# Console Handler
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
gstream = "/Applications/Google Drive File Stream.app"
gdrive = "/Applications/Google Drive.app"

##################################################################################
# Functions
##################################################################################
def appExist(appName):
    logging.info("Checking for the existence of: %s", appName)
    return os.path.exists(appName)

def appProcessID(appPath, action):
    # the "action" item takes either a "kill" or "check" action.
    global appName
    #appName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(appPath))[0]
    appName = os.path.basename(appPath)
    logging.debug('AppName variable and action to be taken is: %s, %s', appName, action)
    if action == "check":
        logging.info('Looking for Process ID(s) for %s', appName)
        process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-i', appName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    global my_pid
    my_pid, err = process.communicate()
    # Check if the application is running and log status
    #my_pid = appProcessID(gdrive)
    if my_pid:
        logging.debug('Application %s is running with process ID(s): %s', gdrive, my_pid)
    else:
        logging.debug('Application %s, is not running. Could not find any process id(s)', appName)
        return my_pid
    elif action == "kill":
        if not my_pid:
            appExit('No Process ID was found.')
        try:
            pid = int(my_pid)
            logging.debug('Converted %s to an integar acceptable for signal killing.', pid)
            #print "that worked"
        except ValueError:
            appExit('Could not confirm ' + my_pid + 'as an integar value acceptable for signal kill.')
            #print "did not work"
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
    else:
        appExit('Could not run the function appProcessID wihtout an action argument.')


def googleDirLookup(directory):
    #UsersGoogleDriveDir = "/Users/" + userName + "/" + appName + "/"
    logging.info('Verifying if this path exists: %s', directory)
    if os.path.exists(directory):
        googleDriveDir = directory
        if os.path.islink(googleDriveDir):
            dir = os.path.realpath(googleDriveDir)
            googleDriveDir = dir + "/"
                logging.info('The path was a symlink and has been updated to use the real path.')
        else:
            googleDriveDir = directory + "/"
            logging.info('Found the directory %s', googleDriveDir)
            return googleDriveDir
    else:
        logging.info('Could not find the path: %s', directory)

def renameDir(olddir, newdir):
    logging.info('Renaming %s to %s', olddir, newdir)
    os.rename(olddir, newdir)
    time.sleep(3)

def Uninstall(appName):
    logging.info('Killing any processes from %s', appName)
    appProcessID(appName, "kill")
    logging.info('Checking if process was killed successfully...')
    appProcessID(appName, "check")
    logging.info('Deleting %s...', appName)
    time.sleep(5)
    if os.path.exists(appName):
        shutil.rmtree(appName)
    else:
        logging.info('Could not find the path: %s', appName)
        # Rename Google Drive folder if it exists
    if not os.path.exists(RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir):
        renameDir(UsersGoogleDriveDir, RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir)
        appExit('Successful! New path is set to ' + RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir)
    else:
            appExit('Failed! Could not find the path: ' + RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir)


def openFileCheck(directory):
    p1=subprocess.Popen(['lsof', '-Fn'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2=subprocess.Popen(['grep', directory + "/"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p3=subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-v', '.DS_Store'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process = p3.communicate()[0]
    if process:
        return process

def installApp(appName):
    if not appExist(appName):
        print appName
        appExit('FAILED to find the installer from ' + appName)
    mountedGDFS = "/Volumes/GoogleDriveFileStream"
    logging.info('Found %s...mounting to %s...', appName, mountedGDFS)
    # Mount DMG
    p1=subprocess.Popen(['hdiutil', 'attach', '-mountpoint', mountedGDFS, appName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
    if not os.path.exists(mountedGDFS + "/GoogleDriveFileStream.pkg"):
        appExit('FAILED to mount directory')
    gdfsPKG = mountedGDFS + "/GoogleDriveFileStream.pkg"
    logging.info('Successfully mounted %s.', mountedGDFS)
    logging.info('Installing PKG from %s...', gdfsPKG)
    p1=subprocess.Popen(['installer', '-pkg', gdfsPKG, '-target', '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
    if not appExist(gstream):
        p2=subprocess.Popen(['hdiutil', 'attach', '-mountpoint', mountedGDFS, appName], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
        appExit('FAILED could not find Google Drive File Stream in ' + gstream)
    # Detach mounted DMG
    logging.info('Unmounting Installer DMG...')
    d1=subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    d2=subprocess.Popen(['grep', mountedGDFS], stdin=d1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    diskDrive =  d2.stdout.readline()[0:12]
    detachCommand=subprocess.Popen(['hdiutil', 'detach', diskDrive], stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).wait()
    if not os.path.exists(mountedGDFS):
        logging.info('Successfully unmounted %s', appName)
    else:
        logging.info('Failed to unmount %s', appName)

def appExit(exitstatement):
    logging.info("%s", exitstatement)
    logging.info('==============END==========================')
    logging.info(' ')
    sys.exit()

##################################################################################
# Check Logic
##################################################################################
# Check and create log files if they do not exist.
logging.info('==============START========================')
logging.info('Location of logs: %s', logFile)
logging.info('Current logged in user: %s', userName)

# Check for the existence of the application before installing.
logging.info('Checking for the existence of application: %s', gstream)
gStreamExist = "FALSE"
if os.path.exists(gstream):
    logging.info('Found the application %s', gstream)
    gStreamExist="TRUE"
    # DO NOT EXIT HERE FOR PRODUCTION
    #appExit(gstream + ", is installed on this system, no need to continue.")
else:
    logging.info('Could not find the application: %s', gstream)

# Check if Google Drive is installed.
logging.info('Checking for the existence of application: %s', gdrive)
gDriveExist = "TRUE"
if not os.path.exists(gdrive):
    gDriveExist="FALSE"
    # DO NOT EXIT HERE FOR PRODUCTION
    #appExit(gdrive + ", is installed on this system")
else:
    logging.info('Found the application: %s', gdrive)

# Check if the application is running and log status
appProcessID(gdrive, "check")
appName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(appName))[0]

# Check for Google Drive folder and for any open files from the application's directory.
UsersGoogleDriveDir = "/Users/" + userName + "/" + appName
RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir = os.path.dirname(UsersGoogleDriveDir) + "/.RENAMED_" + appName
folderRenamed = "FALSE"
if googleDirLookup(UsersGoogleDriveDir):
    logging.info('Checking to see if any open files exist for %s in %s', appName, UsersGoogleDriveDir)
    openFiles = openFileCheck(UsersGoogleDriveDir)
    if openFiles:
        logging.debug('Currently open files include: %s', openFiles)
        appExit("Found actively open files in the directory. Cannot continue at this time.  Quitting script...")
        logging.info('No open files found, continuing...')
elif googleDirLookup(RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir):
    logging.info('Already renamed user\'s home folder.  No need to continue.')
    folderRenamed = "TRUE"
else:
    logging.info('No Google Drive folder found in users home directory.')

##################################################################################
# Action Logic
##################################################################################
if gStreamExist =='FALSE' and gDriveExist =='FALSE' and folderRenamed =='FALSE':
    # Install Google Drive File Stream
    # 1) Check if installer is in place
    # 2) Install if found
    logging.info('== Taking action to Install Google Drive File Stream ==')
    installApp(gdfsInstaller)
    appExit('Successful!')
elif gStreamExist =='FALSE' and gDriveExist =='TRUE' and folderRenamed =='FALSE':
    logging.info('== Taking action to Install GDFS & Uninstall GDrive ==')
    # Install Google Drive File Stream
    # 1) Check if installer is in place
    # 2) Install if found
    installApp(gdfsInstaller)
    # Uninstall Google Drive
    # 1) Kill Process
    # 2) Remove delete application from Applications folder
    # 3) Rename Google Drive folder in user's home directory
    Uninstall(gdrive)
    appExit('Successful!')
elif gStreamExist =='TRUE' and gDriveExist =='TRUE' and folderRenamed =='FALSE':
    logging.info('== Taking action to Uninstall Gdrive ==')
    # Uninstall Google Drive
    # 1) Kill Process
    # 2) Remove delete application from Applications folder
    # 3) Rename Google Drive folder in user's home directory
    Uninstall(gdrive)
    appExit('Successful!')
elif gStreamExist =='TRUE' and gDriveExist =='FALSE' and folderRenamed =='FALSE':
    logging.info('== Taking action to Rename Gdrive Directory ==')
    # 3) Rename Google Drive folder in user's home directory
    renameDir(UsersGoogleDriveDir, RenamedUsersGoogleDriveDir)
    appExit('Successful!')
    #else gStreamExist =='TRUE' and gDriveExist =='FALSE' and folderRenamed =='TRUE':
    # Ideal scenario, do nothing!
else:
    appExit('== NO ACTION TAKEN: Google Drive File Stream is installed, Google Drive is uninstalled, and ' + userName + " Google Drive folder is renamed.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/184672/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.